# How can an Azure website determine which region it is running in?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-traffic-manager

I will be placing an Azure website, in several regions.  Then configuring the Azure Traffic Manager to distribute requests to each region.

The website needs to know which region it is running in.   Is there an API available to determine this?  Or, is my only choice, to define a REGION app setting, that is set appropriately for each Azure website?

Comment: Have you tried Googling for this? You might be able to get a learning bump and answer your own question in the same go..

Comment: Hey, I see this question is also on MSDN social forums with an answer. Recommend following the advice there.

Comment: @Lizz:  I did Google first. The only answer I found was to use an app setting. All of the answers, I found, were fairly old. Microsoft is constantly adding new features to Azure.  So I posted the question to see if Microsoft had added something more recently.

Comment: @Simon: I posted the question here before I received the reply on the Microsoft forum.

Comment: You can mark your answer as the answer by clicking the green checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a response, to my question, on the [Microsoft Azure DNS and Traffic Manager forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/home?forum=windowsazureconnectivity).

The answer was:

> There's no handy way currently. In the Azure Powershell, you could use Get-AzureWebsite to read the WebSpace value, which is structured as Region+"webspace".
>
> For now it's easier to just add it to the app setting, like you suggested. We'll have the region value as an environment variable in a later release.

So, as suggested, we will just use an app setting to tell the website what region it is running in.  We will switch over, to the environment variable, when it becomes available.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same question today, and found this thread. It seems that Web Apps now do include the promised environment variable showing the region in which they are deployed.

I simply used:

```
string region = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REGION_NAME");
```

and it worked fine (note that it returns null when run outside Azure e.g. in Visual Studio).

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, am also trying to get my region of website as display in my contact page. For that, i went with your above suggestion which is giving absolute result. Actually am deployed my application into an Virtual Machine and tried get the region of it by using the above suggestion, but its not working in these case. Why because it is comes under localhost of it which is other than the Azure(i.e., Local Host). For this situation, how to get my application region to display

Comment: Here are the available environment variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings